# Align the text in flushright block

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I had two different lines into a block `flushright`.it is so:

```
           Foo
Hello Everyone
```

I would align these two lines in this way:

```
Foo
Hello Everyone
```

Edit:

```
\begin{flushright}
Foo
Hello Everyone
\end{flushright}
```

I would align `Foo` to the second line

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. It should include your existing code using the `flushright` environment. Have you tried `flushleft`?

Comment: Edited and insert an example

Comment: Use `\begin{flushright} Foo \par Hello Everyone \end{flushright}` or `\begin{flushleft} Foo \par Hello Everyone \end{flushleft}` or use ``\\`` instead of `\par`. It depends on your usage/implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `tabular`:

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Foo \\
Hello everyone
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
```

With `@{}` we remove the default space that's inserted also at the left and right of a `tabular`.